# What does aaa mean?

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, cisco-commands, authentication, aaa

In the below configuration, what does `aaa` mean?

```
aaa authentication login CON local
aaa authentication login VTY group VTY local    
aaa authentication dot1x default group DOT1x
aaa authorization exec VTY group VTY if-authenticated
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

That stands for Authentication, Authorization, and Accounting. It controls who is authorized on a device, what authorization each has, and accounting of who is doing what.

Cisco has documents, e.g. [*Cisco IOS Security Configuration Guide, Release 12.2*](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_2/security/configuration/guide/fsecur_c/scfaaa.html), that explain what it is and how it works on Cisco devices.